How can I add a signature to an email message in New Outlook
I need to be able to add signature programmatically to an email message when user composes or replies to a message. In Classic Outlook it is easily done by simply using a different .HTM file from %appdata%\Microsoft\Signatures.
However, in New Outlook the signatures I create using View > Accounts > Signatures are not stored in the above folder, and I can't find where they are stored... (maybe somewhere online?)
Any ideas?

The New Outlook is based off the Outlook.com engine, so it could be somewhere online?

"somewhere online?" right...

You should press the view button on the top left and then click on the view settings option from the changing menu underneath. In this settings section, you should go to the "Compose and reply" section from the e-mail settings. Then you have to create a new signature and add its content. You should remember that there are save or discard buttons at the bottom right. If you do not register here, your e-mail signature will not be registered and will not appear. Then, at the bottom of the section where you added the content, there is a select box where you can select the new e-mail or the signature you will use to reply to e-mails. You can then save and use it.

This is a coding question - not a use question.
